# Requires of three files are giving me three of the same objects

Tags: node.js, export, require, node-modules

I am importing three js modules that I made into a program but whenever I run any of them, they always run the exported function of the last imported file.

```
x = require("./modules/x/x");
y = require("./modules/y/y");
z = require("./modules/z/z");
```

and in each of those files is a function exported as:

```
module.exports = { runX/Y/Z }
```

I would expect runX to run for x.runX, runY for y.runY and runZ for z.runZ.
However, the function that actually runs is which ever was imported last.

The code inside the modules looks something like this

```
const juergenJSON = require("./juergen.json");
noArg = async channel => {
};
oneArg = async (arg1, channel) => {};
twoArg = async (arg1, arg2, channel) => {};

runJuergen = options => {
  const juergen = options;

  juergen.twoArgs
    ? twoArg(juergen.arg1, juergen.arg2, juergen.channel)
    : juergen.oneArgs
    ? oneArg(juergen.arg1, juergen.channel)
    : noArg(juergen.channel);
};

module.exports = { runJuergen };
```

They are called like so

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const auth = require("./auth.json");

let reddit = require("./modules/reddit/reddit.js");

let juergen = require("./modules/juergen/juergen.js");

let joe = require("./modules/joe/joe.js");

// Create an instance of a Discord client
const client = new Client();

/**
 * The ready event is vital, it means that only _after_ this will your bot start reacting to information
 * received from Discord
 */
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot Loaded");
});

client.on("message", message => {
  let name;
  let arg1;
  let arg2;

  const temp = message.content.split(" ");
  const channel = message.channel;

  name = temp[0].substr(1);
  arg1 = temp[1];
  arg2 = temp[2];

  let oneArgs;
  let twoArgs;
  arg1 && true ? (oneArgs = true) : (oneArgs = false);
  arg1 && arg2 ? (twoArgs = true) : (twoArgs = false);

  const options = {
    name: name,
    arg1: arg1,
    arg2: arg2,
    oneArgs: oneArgs,
    twoArgs: twoArgs,
    channel: channel
  };

  switch (name.toLowerCase()) {
    case "reddit":
    console.log("hello");
      reddit.runReddit(options);
      break;
    case "juergen":
      juergen.runJuergen(options);
      break;
    case "joe":
      joe.runJoe(options);
      break;

    case "max":
      tea(arg1, message);
      break;

      break;
  }
});
```

I know that there are some similar posts out there to this, but I'm having trouble understanding them so a response specific to my situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me the part that your imported functions are call ?

Comment: I've added it to the original post - all of the files are very similar to that, but different things are done inside the oneArg twoArg and noArg functions and the exported names are different as I said :)

Comment: However, I don't think its an issue with these modules, I put a console.log statements inside them when I was expecting them to run and I didn't see any output

Comment: Can you show me the part that where x.runX, y.runY, z.runZ are call please.

Comment: Added them to the original post

Comment: Did your `client.on("message"` fired more than 1 time ?

Comment: No, and the switch statement gets into the correct bit, but it's like it's running one of the other modules. If I remove one of the requires then it runs the new last require

Answer (score 0):

Defining each const locally to its case in the switch statement solved the issue